# Excel output a specific number of a given value input

Tags: excel, numbers, payment

I want to input a certain number and amount of payments and have them write to cells in a row. Ex. 6 pays of $100.00, 12 pays of $200.00. I would like to have 18 cells in a row show $100 6 times then $200 12 times. Any advice? I need the range to be vary based on the total number of payments.

Answer (score 0):

Is this more of what you are looking for? Where the Payment amounts are in the first column.

```
Sub InputData()

Dim inputQty As Integer
Dim inputAmount As Integer
On Error GoTo errorHandler
inputQty = InputBox("Enter in the quantity of payments", "Payment Quantity", "XX", vbOKCancel)
inputAmount = InputBox("Enter the amount for each payment", "Payment Amount", "$XXX.xx", vbOKCancel)

If Range("A2").Value = "" Then
    Range("A1").Select
Else
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
End If

Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To inputQty
      ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0) = inputAmount
    Next i

errorHandler:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the user be able to enter the quantities and the amounts multiple times.  Here I have come up with something for you to start:

```
Sub DataInput()

Dim inQty As Long
Dim inAmt As Long
Dim response As Integer
Dim i As Integer

i = 0
[A1].Select

response = MsgBox("Do you want to enter?", vbYesNo, "Enter?")

Do Until (response = vbNo)
    inQty = InputBox("Please enter the quantity of payments", "Payment Quantity", 1)
    inAmt = InputBox("Enter the amount for each payment", "Payment Amount", 0)

    For i = i + 1 To inQty + i
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0) = inAmt
    Next i
    response = MsgBox("Do you want to enter more?", vbYesNo, "Enter?")
    i = i - 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Please let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score -1):

How about this formula:

```
=IF(SUM($A$2:A2)<$E$1*0.8;200;IF(SUM($A$2:A2)<$E$1;100;""))
```

This make the following assumptions: The target value is in $E$1 and you enter a 0 into A2 (you can hide this row if it bothers you). You then apply the formulate all cells from A3 downward.

The formula will assumes that there will be twice as many large installments as there are small installments. That 80% of the total payments (=0.8) will be made in 200$ installments and only the other 20% installments of 100$. So the formula tracks the running sum of the payments (SUM($A$2:A2)) and compare it to the target value in $E$1 * 0.8. If it is lower it will set the installment to 200. If it is not, it will check if the total is already reached, and add 100 if necessary. If the total is reached it will show an empty cell.

Comment: I guess I should rephrase. I need to be able to enter multiple number of pays and multiple payment amounts. For instance it could be 2 pays of $50, 6 pays of $150, 12 pays of $250, 24 pays of $300. The payment amount and number of payments will be input by a user and the output will be a row of the sequential payments.